# Not able to import org.springframework.security classes in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-security

I have installed Spring and Spring Security Extension (latest version 3.6.4.201503051146) in Eclipse Luna but I am still unable to access the security package. When I write "org.springframework." I cannot see "security". 
I am trying few examples regarding JAAS security and especially JaasAuthenticationToken.

It is also weird that there aren't many examples on the internet regarding JaasAuthenticationToken. Is it deprecated or does it have a hole security?

I also have Maven installed.

Thanks

Comment: You mean it does not prompt you with "security"? Is the security JAR in the build-path for your project?

Comment: :s well I just added the Security Extension Plugin. So I though it would be available after installing it. Should I also add its JAR in that case? I even made a Spring project just to be sure it is working at lease, but I didn't see the security part. I can see the springframework package though. 
Where should I get the JAR then? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I got it. I had to go to pom.xml and add the following code:

```
dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It can be found here : http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

I can see
    `org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.JaasAuthenticationToken`

I would like to thank myself too ^^ .

Comment: I can the check under the voting arrows on the left but it said to wait till tomorrow.